# Issue with variable input type any for cidr block with terragrunt

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-vpc, terragrunt

I have an issue with using the input variable **vpc_cidr_block="10.170.0.0/16"** in my terragrunt.hcl file for a vpc module. The configuration is directly below.

**main.tf**

```
resource "aws_vpc" "main" {
  cidr_block           = var.vpc_cidr_block
  instance_tenancy     = "default"
  enable_dns_support   = var.enable_dns_support
  enable_dns_hostnames = var.enable_dns_hostnames

  tags = merge(
    { environment = var.environment },
    { Name = "${var.name}" },
    var.tags,
    var.additional_tags,
  )
}
```

**variables.tf**

```
variable "vpc_cidr_block" {
  description = "vpc cidr block"
  type        = any
}
```

**terragrunt.hcl**

```
inputs = {
  environment                   = "${local.env.locals.env}-${local.env.locals.account}"
  name                          = "${local.env.locals.env}-${local.env.locals.name}-${basename(get_original_terragrunt_dir())}"
  vpc_cidr_block                =  "10.170.0.0/16"
  tags                          = local.env.locals.tags

}
```

However, I receive the below error after running terragrunt apply.

**error msg**

```
error: Invalid number literal
│ 
│   on <value for var.vpc_cidr_block> line 1:
│   (source code not available)
│ 
│ Failed to recognize the value of this number literal.

│ Error: No value for required variable
│ 
│   on variables.tf line 50:
│   50: variable "vpc_cidr_block" {
│ 
│ The root module input variable "vpc_cidr_block" is not set, and has no
│ default value. Use a -var or -var-file command line argument to provide a
│ value for this variable.
```

#### It DOES work successfully if I do either of the below:

1. change the ***type = any*** to ***type = string***. However, because the underlying module here is being shared by other configurations, making this permanent may introduce a breaking change elsewhere.
2. create a tfvars file and place in the same directory as my terragrunt.hcl file, then run ***terragrunt apply -var-file=myvars.tfvars***. The issue with this is, I am setting up a GitHub actions pipeline to deploy terragrunt and just simply wanted to run a *terragrunt run-all apply* to deploy all of my different modules.

#### It does NOT work if i try the below

1. *terragrunt apply -var vpc_cidr_block="10.170.0.0/16"*. This returns the same error message above.

#### Question

Why does it work with the tfvars file but not when consuming it as an input variable in the terragrunt.hcl file as the variable type is still set to *any*? And any advice how to best tackle this?

Comment: It should always be of type `string` if you are defining it that way.

Comment: any idea of why the terragrunt input can't read it properly in comparison to when i pass the same input value via a tfvars file?

Comment: I know very little about how files are organized in your project to make an educated guess.

Comment: To get around this issue, i've created an override.tf file in the same dir as the terragrunt.hcl file for now, and am passing the variable block type=string via it. Still unsure why the tfvars works but the input in the terragrunt.hcl file doesn't.